# Windows Service - ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Nome da fonte de dados não encontrado e nenhum driver padrão especificado

Tags: c#, oracle, odbc

Eu tenho 2 projetos (WebForms e Windows Services) em .NetFramework 4 que se conecta a base Oracle através do ObdcConnection.

No projeto Web eu consigo abrir a conexão com sucesso...

Porém no Windows Services é lançado o seguinte erro:

**ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Nome da fonte de dados não encontrado e nenhum driver padrão especificado**

Em Inglês: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

Nos dois projetos eu estou usando o seguinte método:

```
public void testConnectionObdc(string connectionString)
{
   OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
   conn.Open();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Tente mudar as permissões que seu Windows Service executa, pelo jeito parece que que o serviço não tem permissão para acessar as fontes de dados ODBC, você pode fazer isso através do gerenciador de serviço do Windows (pressione WinKey + R, digite services.msc e pressione enter). Na lista de serviços, procure o seu serviço, clique com o botão direito, na segunda aba (Log On), defina uma outra conta para executar este serviço preferencialmente com permissões administrativas para ter certeza que o problema será resolvido caso seja permissão. Após isso, basta reiniciar o serviço.

Comment: obrigado, era isso!